# Setting OPTGROUP label with jquery

Tags: jquery, select, optgroup

I struggle to find how to change my opt label by ID with Jquery :

I've tried the following with no luck :

```
$("#o1").attr('label').change('New DAY') ;
```

And this one too :

```
 $("#o1").attr('label').append('New DAY');
```

This is my html :

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropdown_appointment">
                        <option value="choose">Choisir le Rendez-vous.  </option>
                        <optgroup label="Lundi" id="o1">
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Mardi" id="o2">
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Mercredi" id="o3">
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Jeudi" id="o4">
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Vendredi" id="o5">
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Samedi" id="o6">
                        </optgroup>

                    </select> <br><br>
```

Maybe you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#o1").attr('label','New DAY');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try tomorrow